# Sending datas from webworker to site context failing

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-worker

i'm trying to pass data from webworker to main context but i can't make it work. My code is:

```
alg.OnProcessEnd = (arg: { array: Uint32Array, max: number }) => {
    (<any>self).postMessage(arg, [arg.array]);
};
```

but chrome claims that "TypeError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': Value at index 0 does not have a transferable type."

so my question is: How to send properly data from webworker where I can't make copy (image data array).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to serialize the `Uint32Array` first, transfer it over, then deserialize it.

One way to do that is by transforming it into a JSON array by doing:

```
var jsonArray = '[' + Array.prototype.join.apply(arg.array, [',']) + ']';
```

Then you can transfer that over and recreate the `Uint32Array` object by doing:

```
var uint32Array = new Uint32Array( JSON.parse(jsonArray) );
```

**Edit:**

As transferable object: You were missing the `buffer` property.

```
(<any>self).postMessage(arg, [arg.array.buffer]);
```

Comment: shouldn't be possible do it by transferable object?

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter should be the buffer not the array itself

```
alg.OnProcessEnd = (arg: { array: Uint32Array, max: number }) => {
    (<any>self).postMessage(arg, [arg.array.buffer]);
};
```